# join two tables in codeigniter and refere to two fields in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My application works like this: α user creates a task and assigns it
to another user.  I have two tables 
(user table)
user_name

AND

(task table)
task_subject
creator
assigned_to

my question how to make join statement by codeigniter to display
the task, its creator name and assigned to whom.

Comment: check the query I have posted hopefully it will work for you perfectly @hasanali

Comment: i already did the join but i can only get one user for the task . the creator or the assigned only one

Answer (score 0):

Please check following query for join in codeigniter

```
       $user   = 'user';
       $task   = ' task,';

    $this->db->select($user.'.*,'.$task.'.*');
    $this->db->from($task); 
    $this->db->join($user,
            $task.'.user_id = '.$user.'.user_id'
    );
    $this->db->join($user,$user.'.user_id = $task.'created_by','left');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;
    }
    return FALSE;
```

Instead of using * you can use your own custom fields that you want to show and in join use the common id in both tables like I use user_id

Comment: i already wrote the same query, but as i said before this will return only one user name , the creator or the assigned

Comment: $this->db->join($user,
            $task.'.creator = '.$user.'.user_id'

Comment: $this->db->join($user,
            $task.'.assigned = '.$user.'.user_id'

Comment: I have just updated the query can you try it again. @hassan ali

Comment: this is the print of sql : SELECT task.*, user.user_name FROM task JOIN user ON user.user_id = task.creator_id LEFT JOIN user ON user.user_id = task.task_assigned_to